# Did Sri Ramanuja convert atheists?

Tags: history, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya

Sri Ramanuja, the great Vaishnava acharya and the propounder of Vishishtadvaita philosophy, is known to have converted many Buddhists and Jains back to Hinduism.

What about atheists? Did he convert any atheists? If yes, how did he convert atheists back to Hinduism?

So I want to know if there is any legend where Sri Ramanuja came in contact with atheists and converted them. If yes, then how?

Note: By "atheists" here, I mean those who do not believe in any existence of God.

Comment: I think there is no such incidence and atheism leads to loss of once caste.

Comment: Ramanujacharya was not the founder f Vishishtadvaita. This concept was already there before him.

Comment: Buddhists are atheists.

Comment: Buddhists are Nastiks (don't consider Vedas as supreme), that doesn't mean they are atheists. Atheists are is an Abhramic understanding not Dharmic (which includes Hndus, Jains, Buddhists, Sikhs)

Comment: @Akhil These are different types of categorisations. I agree that Buddhists are Dharmic, however, they are also atheists since they don't believe in any kind of Brahman.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Buddhist Belive In karma,Rebirth,Moksha,I meant to say atheist who are similiar to charvaka sect.Not Buddhist type.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda you can edit saying you are asking for Non-Dharmic Atheists to make the question clearer.

Comment: Charvakas metaphysically are not Dharmic but the existential world view is still Dharmic hence they are also part of Dharmic traditions. On the other hand Atheists share the world view of Christianity (not the "religious" view) hence are "ADharmic" doesn't mean they are Nastik....Nastik cannot be translated to  Atheist  (Once of those Sanskrit non translatable just like Dharma != Religion, Varna != Caste, Jati != Caste)

Comment: Vaduga Nambi is a good example of such a convert.